# How do I change the base adress with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, x86

How do I change the base address in GCC like in assembly if you would do:

```
org <address>
```

I’m compiling the source into an object and then use "objcopy" to get only the .text field out of it and put it into a binary file to execute (I’m creating a C kernel).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a *linker script* to a linker in order to make a custom sections layout. Check with `binutils` documentation at the [SourceWare site](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html).